# Proper way to mask a URL in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mask, redirect

Trying to mask a URL in .htaccess but it doesn't seem to be happening for me. I get the page on my site and not the one I want people to see. This is what I'm using in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^member-login/?$ https://www.somesite.com//login/
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you include the `https://www.somesite.com` portion in your rule's destination, *it will inherently **redirect** the browser*, even without the `R` flag. Assuming that the htaccess file is in the document root for the `www.somesite.com` site, then you can just remove that part of the rule (and add a `L` flag for safe measure):

```
RewriteRule ^member-login/?$ /login/ [L]
```

If the htaccess file *isn't* in the somesite document root, then you need to setup a reverse proxy.

Comment: How do you do a reverse proxy? The URL we want to mask is on a different URL than where the .htaccess will be.

Comment: @AdamBell you need access to the server's config, not htaccess.